# Automator subfolder workflow

Tags: automator, subdirectory

Running Mac OS 10.10.3 
I edit videos for a living. Frequently, clients give me a mess of files that are all disorganized into subdirectories of folders. 
I want to select a parent folder, and in Finder Services > run an Automator workflow that looks through all subfolders, finds Photo files, finds Video files, and then puts them into corresponding new folders named PHOTOS and VIDEOS, inside that parent folder I selected. I don't know much about how to use variables, but need help stringing together an Automator Service to pull it off. Currently I have:

Set Value of Variable: hostfolder

Get Folder Contents: repeat for each subfolder found

Filter Finder Items: All > File extension > contains > mov or MOV

Move Finder Items: ???

Any help completing this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Use two more **Set Value of Variable**s at the very beginning, and set one up for PHOTOS and the other for VIDEOS.  Move your videos to the proper path, then the PHOTOS.  I am not sure you can do this with a single Workflow, unless you ask it to analyze *hostfolder* a second time to find all the photo files.  If that works, you should still only need to define the final destination folders once.